# Play Framework 2.4 Ebean Id Generation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

until now we have been using Play 2.3.9 and we are now migrating to Play 2.4.1 When I use the old version of Play saving an Entity works but with the new verion the Id is not generated. I setup a new project from scratch and tried it to realize it works and the auto generated database has an Id field that auto increments while the old project has a database that uses sequences. I have been trying to configure play/ebean to use sequences but have not been succesfull thus far.

I took a look here http://www.avaje.org/topic-97.html and gave it a try but its still not working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My config looks like this:

```
ebean.default.identityGeneration=sequence
ebean.default.supportsGetGeneratedKeys=false
ebean.default.supportsSequences=true
ebean.default.debug.sql=true
```

I also tried with

```
ebean.default.identityGeneration=generator
```

I put the lines directly in application.conf I also fooled around with the ServerConfigStartup way of configuring ebean but no luck.

Answer (score 6):

Anyways, I got it to work, if anyone has the same problem the following fixes it:

```
public class MyServerConfigStartup implements ServerConfigStartup {
@Override
public void onStart(ServerConfig serverConfig) {
    PostgresPlatform postgresPlatform = new PostgresPlatform();
    DbIdentity dbIdentity = postgresPlatform.getDbIdentity();
    dbIdentity.setSupportsGetGeneratedKeys(false);
    dbIdentity.setSupportsSequence(true);
    dbIdentity.setIdType(IdType.GENERATOR);
    serverConfig.setDatabasePlatform(postgresPlatform);
}
```

}

Comment: Reference of https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/97  With Ebean version 4.0.5 on Postgres SERIAL became the default ID mechanism.   Your solution above is good - alternatively you could use the older "platform" by:  ebean.databasePlatformName=postgres8

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Rob's comment into a real answer:

Putting 

`ebean.databasePlatformName=postgres8`

in `conf/ebean.properties` will force the Play 2.3 default of using a PostgreSQL Sequence to generate IDs.