# After the Migration play 2.4, use an existing sequence of the postgresdb to generate the id of Play-2.4 Entity

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

We have been using Play 2.3.9 and we are now migrating to Play 2.4.1 When I use the old version of Play saving an Entity works but with the new verion the Id is not generated.

If I use,

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

it's working fine, but when am using,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

in Model getting below Exception

```
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint\n   Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, kumar, null, 9581672143, kumar@gmail.com, +j+b2lc5C7B48IGct2+L1jKBEIXhl0aOYy1BOnb85/Q=, iCZqST2EU4ECVaPwzGxr1hZ/b4Da34BI/C9xKCbpo78=, null, null, null, f, f, null, BLOOD_BANK_ADMIN, null, f, f, null, null, null, null, t, f, 2015-08-03 15:53:47.308, 2015-08-03 15:53:47.309, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null).]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:90) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.insert(DmlBeanPersister.java:57) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeInsertBean(DefaultPersistExecute.java:59) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:446) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:480) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since ebean 4.0.5, id genration strategy has changed from IDENTITY to GENERATOR. 
workaround: [Play Framework 2.4 Ebean Id Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071253/play-framework-2-4-ebean-id-generation)